# implement a animation class on java libgdx

Tags: java, class, libgdx

I'm creating a 2D game, and I want to create a class to handle all the animations present in the scene, not the player animation or the npcs but just the animations that are fixed on the scene.  The basic idea is, I have a background, and then some animations on fix locations.

this is what I have created so far

```
public class Animation extends MyGdxGame{

    private Animation<TextureRegion> animaction; 
    private Texture walkSheet;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    private float stateTime;
    private float x,y,velocidade;
    private final MyGdxGame app;


    public Animation (final MyGdxGame app, String file, int col, int lin, float x,float y, float vel) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.velocidade=velocidade;
        this.app = app;

        walkSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(file));


        TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet, 
                walkSheet.getWidth() / col,
                walkSheet.getHeight() / lin);


        TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[col * lin];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
            }
        }


        animaction = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.025f, walkFrames);


        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        stateTime = 0f;



    }

     @Override
    public void render() {

        stateTime +=  Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();


        TextureRegion currentFrame = animaction.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

        app.batch.draw(currentFrame, x, y);



    }

     @Override
    public void dispose() { 
        spriteBatch.dispose();
        walkSheet.dispose();
    }

}
```

the scene and the animations are loaded from the beginning, my problem is that my animations are not being drawn,
to load the animation this is the way I call the class

```
for (int i = 0;i<number_of_animations;ii++)
    animation = new Animation(....);
```

and by just call it this way and because it uses the `@Override` on the `draw` function I thought it was enough to draw the animations, still makes me a lot of confusion using extends on classes.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: I don't think this class should be extending your game class. You should not be creating a new SpriteBatch in this class but rather using the one from your game class. Can't debug any more than that without seeing your game class.

Answer (score 0):

my solution was, remove the  `extends MyGdxGame` and the `@Override` annotation, then declare it as an array

```
for...
{
    animation[count] = new Animacao(...);
    count++;
}
```